# android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout, runtimeexception, drawerlayout

My application was working fine but when i try to add a side menu on left of my Main Class, I get error on line 75  and i don't understand, please help me.

```
line 75: mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

MainDrawer.java

```
package com.android.moyenne.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import com.android.activity.R;
import com.android.moyenne.ansco.ListAnSco;

public class MainDrawer extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment aide = new Aide();
    Fragment about = new About();
    Fragment moyenne = new MoyenneMain();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private static String aideTitle, aboutTitle,studentTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_striped);
                bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

                BitmapDrawable bgSplit = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_striped_split_img);
                bgSplit.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
                getSupportActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(bgSplit);
            }

        // Get the Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Generate title
        aideTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.aide);
        aboutTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.about);
        studentTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_title);
        title = new String[] { studentTitle, aideTitle, aboutTitle };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Menu principal", "Aide sur l'application",
                "A propos de l'application" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.home, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details};
        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainDrawer.this, title, subtitle,
                icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture listview menu item click
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Set the title on the action when drawer open
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, moyenne);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, aide);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, about);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        title = new String[] { studentTitle, aideTitle, aboutTitle};

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Menu principal", "Aide sur l'application",
                "A propos de l'application", "Permet de prendre des notes" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Get the options menu view from menu.xml in menu folder
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        // Show the settings menu item in menu.xml
        MenuItem menuSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);

        // Capture menu item clicks
        menuSettings.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Do something here
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ListAnSco.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return false;
            }

        });

        return true;
        }

        // Capture first menu button click
        OnMenuItemClickListener setButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Create a simple toast message
                Toast.makeText(MainDrawer.this, "Set Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Do something else
                return false;
            }
        };

}
```

drawer_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_striped"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider_bl" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Log:

```
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.activity/com.android.moyenne.activity.MainDrawer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.moyenne.activity.MainDrawer.onCreate(MainDrawer.java:75)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-29 00:28:31.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not able to find any issue in your code. Just try `Project--> Clean` and Run it again after `uninstalling Previous Build` will may probably solve your issue.

Comment: I have Restart Eclipse and wipe all data when opening my AVD and it works fine.
thx

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the exception.

```
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    try {
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_Layout);

        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```